# Directory.Exists returns false after FileSystemWatcher ArgumentException

Tags: c#, .net

Local Drive C is shared in Remote Desktop Connection.
I iterate folders in C\ Program files successfully. But if I add `FileSystemWatcher` to the child folders of Program Files, some of them throw Argument exception - wrong path (which is actually given by `EnumerateDirectories` method !!). Then access to other child folders of C is unexpectedly denied. Here is a sample code:

```
// returns TRUE
var firstTryTrue = Directory.Exists("\\\\tsclient\\C\\DRIVERS");
try
{
    foreach (var item in Directory.EnumerateDirectories("\\\\tsclient\\C\\Program Files"))
    {
        FileSystemWatcher w2 = new FileSystemWatcher(item);
        w2.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.FileName;
        w2.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
        w2.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ee) { }
catch (ArgumentException ae) { }

// returns FALSE
var secondTryFalse = Directory.Exists("\\\\tsclient\\C\\DRIVERS");
```

Comment: did you loose a connection to the server?

Comment: No server, this is remote connection to PC in my network, I still see all files in different APPs but not in my code....